# Record system audio with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, audio-recording

I wanted to record system audio for 5 seconds (Audio is not just from browser tabs, can be from anywhere - system), is it possible to do with chrome extension?

Our intension is to search our servers for matching records(audio search) and present relevant information to users.

Example: If some audio is played by itunes or any software, we just wanted to record audio output directly from anything that is playing on the System.

Any help!

Comment: That docs link is for `native-client` which is an entirely different thing. I guess you can try using some easily googlable existing solutions like [Record Audio Using the Users Microphone with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25101037) or http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to record audio in a Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328309/how-to-record-audio-in-a-chrome-extension). Not voting to close as that has a link only answer

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

Comment: Our requirement is a bit different. We do not want to record audio from the microphone, instead from the current system audio out. Ex: if itunes is playing an audio, we just want to record the audio out for few seconds.

Comment: @Steve, then you'd need your system to route all the audio to some point you could listen at (doable thanks to [Jack](http://www.jackaudio.org/) or [similar](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/)), then you'd just have to set the system output to this virtual device, and use `getUserMedia` with the virtual device as input.

Comment: Ps: for what you want to achieve, a simple drag and drop of the file is still way easier and you'll get better results. (just add a note that they can drag the file directly from the itunes list)

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, Jack seems helpful. Drag n drop require user action, but we want to have this automated. Showing lyrics on browser for a song being played is an example.

Comment: Then I'm not sure the browser is the best place for such an app.